# Batch Job terminating despite answering not to terminate it

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Why is the batch job closing, even if I enter 'N'?:

```
^CTerminate batch job (Y/N)? N
PS C:\path\to\folder>
```

Comment: Pretty much impossible to answer without seeing the batch file and knowing how the batch file was started.

Comment: step number one for debugging a batch file... add `REM ` in front of `@ECHO OFF`.

Comment: Let's take for example the following batch:
`@ECHO OFF
REM DO SOMETHING
ping -n 10 127.0.0.1 >nul
`
It will produce the following output:
`C:\Users\User\Desktop>batch
^CTerminate batch job (Y/N)? N

C:\Users\User\Desktop>`

Why is the batch still terminating, even if I typed in 'N'?

Comment: What I'd like to point out, is that in a long running batch, when trying to terminate, both the options 'Yes' and 'No' terminate the batch, whereas the options 'No' should continue the batch.

Comment: It could be anything. In that example, the script ended because it finished.

Comment: The script didn't terminate yet. If I'm pressing Ctrl + C while the script is running, the event described above occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check it

```
@ECHO OFF 
REM DO SOMETHING
ping -n 10 127.0.0.1 >nul
echo:continued
```

Comment: Doesn't work. While this is running and I'm pressing Ctrl + C, but select `No` when `Terminate batch job (Y/N)?` appears, the batch stills ends. Shouldn't it continue?

Comment: @ThomasGassmann, it's working normally if it prints "continued" after you press Ctrl+C.

Comment: A console application, including cmd.exe, is a client of an instance of the console host (conhost.exe in Windows 7+). When you press Ctrl+C, the console broadcasts a `CTRL_C_EVENT` to every process that's attached to the console. This is implemented by injecting a thread that starts at a known `CtrlRoutine` function. If the process has Ctrl+C enabled, `CtrlRoutine` calls the chain of registered control handler functions until one handles the event. The default handler simply calls `ExitProcess`. ping.exe either relies on the default handler or has one that gracefully exits.